# RT8822BE has weird behavior, wont install 3rd party driver

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, realtek

My laptop has the RT8822BE WiFi chip in it, and is running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It would connect and run properly on bootup, but then cut out completely after about a minute until I reboot. Ubuntu can still detect it, but can't find or connect to any WiFi networks. Another thing is that if I turn on airplane mode, it "pauses" the time until it dies. For the time being, I'm using a USB WiFi adapter for internet.

I tried looking up drivers for it, and came across [r8822be driver from linux-5.1.21](https://github.com/mid-kid/r8822be), which seems to be the one of the only ones from my research. I followed the steps from the answer in [rtl8822be wifi not working ubuntu 18.04 (bluetooth works)](https://superuser.com/a/1581591/1226922), but ran into a problem at the last command, `sudo modprobe r8822be`. It outputs the following message:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8822be': Operation not permitted
```

And enabling verbose, it shows this:

```
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/r8822be.ko
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8822be': Operation not permitted
```

After searching it up a bit, I found out that it has something to do with Secure Boot, which I remember setting up for VirtualBox.

In addition, it now doesn't work at all, as in Ubuntu can't detect it.

I'm new to Linux in general, so I don't really know what I'm doing...

Comment: Check in terminal `mokutill --sb-state`  It likely says Secure Boot enabled and that is why the driver won't load.  You can disable Secure Boot in BIOS settings

Comment: @Jeremy31 Wow, thank you! That worked! Can you post it as the answer for other people? Or should I?